# A problem on polynomial completely

Tags: polynomials, factoring

$P(x)=x^3+mx^2+nx+14$ is divisible by $(x+2)$ but leaves a remainder of $-20$ when it is divided by $(x-2)$. Find the values of $m$ and $n$. Hence, factorise the polynomial completely.

Now, I get $m=-6$ and $n=-9$ but when I factorise the polynomial, the answer is $P(x)=(x+2)(x-2).(x^2-6x-5)+0$. Is it correct?

Comment: Your values of $m$ and $n$ are correct.  Your factorization is not correct.  You do know that $x+2$ is a factor of $P(x)$. The remaining factor should be quadratic, and you can try to factor that further.

Comment: You accepted an answer that explained what you already knew, but gave no explanation at all of the part you asked about. That's puzzling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $(x+2)$ is a factor,
$$\begin{align}
P(x)=x^3+mx^2+nx+14&=(x+2)(x^2+ax+7)\\
&\Rightarrow \begin{cases} m=2+a\\n=2a+7\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

As dividing by $(x-2)$ gives a remainder of $-20$,
$$\begin{align}
P(2)=8+4m+2n+14&=-20\\
4+2m+n+17&=0\\
4+2(2+a)+(2a+7)+17&+0\\
4a&=-32\\
a&=-8\\
&\Rightarrow m=-6, n=-9\qquad \blacksquare\end{align}$$
Note that
$$\begin{align}
P(x)&=(x+2)(x^2-8x+7)=(x+2)(x-7)(x-1)\\
&=x^3-6x^2-9x+14\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not correct. Since $m=-6,n=-9$ (these are correct), we have
$$x^3-6x^2-9x+14=(x-1)(x+2)(x-7).$$

P.S. Note that $P(x)$ is not divisible by $x-2$. Also, you can see 
$$x^3-6x^2-9x+14\not=(x+2)(x-2)(x^2-6x-5)+0$$
only by comparing constant terms in both sides.

Answer (score 0):

The values of $\,m,n\,$ are correct, but the factorization is not. Indeed if it had a factor $\,x-2\,$ then when divided by $\,x-2\,$ it would have remainder $\,0,\,$ not $\:-20.\,$ Since we know that it has a factor $\,x+2\,$ we can use division to find the quadratic cofactor $\,P(x)/(x+2),\,$ then factor that.

More simply, note that the sum of the coefficients of $\,P(x) = x^3-\color{#0a0}6\,x^2-9x+14\,$ is $\,0,\,$ i.e. $\,P(\color{#c00}1) = 0,\,$ so $\color{#c00}1$ is a root, and since the sum of the roots $= \color{#0a0}6,\,$ the third root is $\,\color{#0a0}6\!-\!\color{#c00}1\!-\!(-2) = 7.$